# SVN-Git migration: clean-git branch error

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

I'm following the SVN to Git [migration guide](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/migrating-overview), the `git svn clone` goes fine but when I run the cleanup command I get this error, I'm not even sure what this means. How do I solve this ?

```
java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -jar ~/svn-migration-scripts.jar clean-git
Could not retrieve the config for the key: svn-remote.svn.branches
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This problem comes up when you are not specifying the `--branches` while running the `git svn clone` command. You can avoid it by specifying the `--branches` while executing the `git svn clone` as follows:

```
git svn clone --username=ArpitAggarwal --branches=/dev --authors-file=C:/Users/ArpitAggarwal/authors.txt http://localhost:81/svn/project/branches/ dev-git
```

Still if you don't want to specify `--branches`, a workaround is to add an empty `"branches"` key in `.git/config`, as follows:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = http://localhost:81/svn/project/branches
    branches = 
[svn]
    authorsfile = C:/Users/ArpitAggarwal/authors.txt
```

**For similar error with tags:**

> Could not retrieve the config for the key: svn-remote.svn.tags

add an empty `"tags"` key in `.git/config`, as follows:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = false
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        symlinks = false
        ignorecase = true
        hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
    [svn-remote "svn"]
        url = http://localhost:81/svn/project/branches
        branches = dev/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        tags =  
    [svn]
        authorsfile = C:/Users/ArpitAggarwal/authors.txt
```